# What is the difference between IsAppThemed and IsThemeActive?

Tags: windows, winapi

I can't really understand in which cases I'd want to use [IsAppThemed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759809.aspx) and when I'd want to use [IsThemeActive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759813.aspx).

It seems that on Windows 7, both functions return TRUE with Aero or Windows 7 Basic, and both functions return FALSE with Windows Classic.

From what I understand from the documentation so far, IsAppThemed will always return TRUE beginning with Windows 8. That's about all I can determine - other than that I can't see how I'd prefer one over the other in any case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IsThemeActive() tells you whether visual styles are enabled in the operating system.  Prior to Win8 you could force that off in Control Panel by selecting the Classic style.  Yes, poor name choice.

IsAppThemed() tells you whether the app has enabled visual styles, either by using a manifest or by using ActivateActCtx(), and it wasn't disabled in the operating system.  If IsThemeActive() returns FALSE then IsAppThemed() will always return FALSE.

Comment: OK, I understand both the TRUE/TRUE and FALSE/FALSE cases now... the last one, where IsAppThemed() == TRUE and IsThemeActive() == FALSE, then the application has disabled visual styles through some manner, i.e. the operating system is using Aero or Win7 Basic, but the application itself is using Windows Classic style controls. Is that correct? Seems IsThemeActive() is generally the function to use although I can hardly think of a use case for IsAppThemed() either.

Comment: Well, no, the more common case would be that the app just didn't enable visual styles.  Opting in is explicit, not by accident.  There's no such thing as "Classic style controls", they are all the same, just rendered differently.

Comment: OK, I think I've got a better understanding of the differentiation now - thanks!

Comment: I don't think this has been answered. No one has cited a scene that **IsThemeActive=1** & **IsAppThemed=0**. Using Windows 7, run Charles Petzold *Programming Windows 5th-ed* chap 11 "About2" example with code checking IsThemeActive & IsAppThemed. 
They still shows **both 1**. We know that the Petzold's code from 1998 refers nothing to the comctl32 v6 manifest. Check image here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/G29KT.png

Comment: Hmya, the property name is IsAppThemed, not IsWindowThemed.  Bypassing the application's default behavior is not difficult to do, especially not when using Petzold code.  After 85 questions, you ought to know better than to ask for help in a comment.